# Removing Nested LaTeX Tags with Regex

Tags: regex, sed, latex

How would I use regex (such as with `sed`) to remove all `\index` tags that occur inside any `\index` tags?

For example, a nested mess like this:

```
\index{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}
```

would turn into

```
\index{Testing One Two Three}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a loop.  The following would remove `\index{foo}` as long as it is preceded by a word boundary.

```
sed -r ':a;s/\b\\index\{[^{}]+}//;ta' inputfile
```

For your given sample, it'd produce:

```
\index{Testing One Two Three}
```

However, be warned about using regular expressions for parsing and manipulating such nested patterns.  In case you do, ensure that you observe the `diff` of the input before and after the change.

---

EDIT: Explanation:

Look at the substitution command first:

```
s/\b\\index\{[^{}]+}//g
```

- `\b` matches a boundary between a word character `\w` and a non-word character `\W`.
- `\\index\{` matches `\index{`
- `[^{}]+}` matches one or more of anything that is not `}` followed by `}`

`:a` is a label.  `ta` branches to label `a` if the substitution was successful.

So it would work by removing the innermost `index{}` from the string, such that

```
\index{Test\index{test\index{test}}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}
```

would transform to:

```
\index{Test\index{test}ing One\index{one} Two\index{two} Three\index{three}}
```

and so on until the substitution fails.

Comment: Why does it have to be preceded by a word boundary?

Comment: @Geremia Your input doesn't seem to contain a space before `\index`, so making use of the word boundary seemed like an _obvious exploit_.

Comment: so, would `sed -r ':a;s/\\index\{[^{}]+}//g;ta' inputfile` work? If not, why?

Comment: @Geremia Why not try it?  (It'd remove the entire string in your example.)

Comment: Could you please explain what your extended regexp options here are; I've never heard of regexp looping. Then I'll mark yours as the solution. thanks

Comment: @Geremia Added the explanation to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The following works wherever \index is located,

```
 sed -e 's/\\index{\([^]]*\)}/\\index{}/g' inputfile
```

except .... that it works provided opening and closing braces are located **on the same line**. *sed* does have a number of options (P,N,D) for dealing with patterns which complete on multiple lines, but they work by concatenating two consecutive lines. Since it is possible the braces' {} pattern closes in 3,4,..,n,... lines, this will require some programming.

Alternatively, if you are satisfied with *just locating* matching patterns (*i.e.*, not substituting them), you can use:

```
pcregrep -M '\{(\s*.*\s*)*\}' test.txt
```

where the *-M* option is used to allow *Multiline* patters. This finds zero or more occurrences of (whitespace followed by .* followed by whitespace), provided this is all surrounded by curly braces.

Comment: All my `\index`es are on the same line.

Comment: @Geremia Then you have you solution.